# ContentFlow: load AddOn on creation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using ContentFlow (http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/index.php) to create an image carousel on my page. The images are loaded via a jQuery AJAX-call. This works fine. The ContentFlow is included with this code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="contentflow.js" ></script>
```

Now I want to apply the default 'white' addOn upon creation of the ContentFlow. The CF is created in my document.ready()-codeblock. According to the documentation this should be done like (I believe):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
...
var ajax_cf = new ContentFlow('ajax_cf', {useAddOns : 'white' });
});
```

The ContentFlow is created just fine, the AddOn/theme however, is not applied. When using a non-AJAX approach the theme is applied correctly, so I know for sure the theme works, has no syntax errors, etc.

Any clues?

Comment: The "language" tag has been deprecated, and you can safely remove it. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxjscript/thread/65aaf5f3-09db-4f7e-a32d-d53e9720ad4c

Answer (score 2):

You need to manually add the addon script into the page.

For example, to include the slideshow addon use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="content_flow/contentflow.js" load="slideshow"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="content_flow/ContentFlowAddOn_slideshow.js"></script>
```

Then the Ajax config. worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Trying to find the answer to something else about ContentFlow, I may have stumbled upon a solution to your issue: http://www.jeremyckahn.com/blog/?p=61

This post basically suggests not to set your ContentFlow configurations in $(document).ready

Additionally, my experience from Oliver Kohll's answer is that you DO need to specify the AddOn you want in the 'load' attribute for inclusion of contentflow.js as above...but you should NOT need to also specify the AddOn.js

Hope this helps!